# Can I talk to friendly humans?

Tags: hack-slash-loot

During the "Battle for Stormrise", you find lots of "Human (friendly)" characters walking about. They'll help you battle any demons that are within view and they don't attack you when you're the only one around. **Can I talk with these characters or get them to follow me?**

The only action I see when mousing over them is "Attack Human (friendly)" so it's not immediately evident how I can accomplish this. There are some achievements for Hack Slash Loot for having (and betraying!) allies which is why I suspect that there are more actions available to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly certain there is no way to get them to ally with you.  The game is made to be played with just the mouse.  If there is no command to be able to talk with just the mouse, you probably can't do it.  Also, the controls listed on the game site ["How to"](http://hackslashloot.com/howto.html) neglect mentioning a way to talk which further leads me to think you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "talk" command, but some ...things... (wink wink) do indeed talk, and when it happens, the game pulls up a special screen (literally, it slides up from the bottom) that displays the text, and you must click the mouse to indicate you are done reading. So it's possible to miss such a screen by clicking rapidly, but even still you'd see the screen sliding up so you'd know you'd missed it. These "talking events" are just filler story, interesting to read, and don't hurt you if you decide not to read.

There are far more options for friendly allies than just humans, too.

The betrayal achievement is earned by killing friendly allies.